# React Context can't be imported

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-context

I am following a tutorial on Youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35lXWvCuM8o

At 17:45s it doesn't `import MovieProvider from "./MovieContext"` but it does when you see the tutorial and I have done everything exactly the same, what could be the reason ?

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import MoviesList from "./MoviesList";
import { Movi } from "./Movie";
import { MovieProvider } from "./MovieProvider";

function App() {
  return (
    <MovieProvider>
      <div className="app">
        <MoviesList />
      </div>
    </MovieProvider>
  );
} 

 export default App;

import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import Movie from "./Movie";
import { MovieContext } from "./Movie";
const MoviesList = () => {
  const value = useContext(MovieContext);
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{value}</h2>
      {/*movies.map(movie => (
        <Movie name={movie.name} price={movie.price} />
      ))*/}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MoviesList;

import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

const Movie = ({ name, price }) => {
  return (
    <div className="movie">
      <h2>{name}</h2>
      <p>{price}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Movie;

import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";

export const MovieContext = createContext();

export const MovieProvider = props => {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([
    { name: "Brave heart", price: "10$" },
    { name: "Mission impossible", price: "20$" },
    { name: "Titatic", price: "5$" }
  ]);

  return (
    <MovieContext.Provider value={"Hello"}>
      {props.children}}
    </MovieContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

PS: I have followed other tutorial where Context API works with classes in same file, It just does not work for me in this Youtube video.

Br
Sara

Comment: Please post your code. Problem can be within your code.

Comment: @SerhiiZharkov Now I have posted my code, if you see MovieProvider Class , it has two exports, MovieProvider is Exported but Movie Context is not exported

Comment: I think you have a typo in `Titatic` :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you follow along the video you should import as following in `App.js`

```
 import { MovieProvider } from './MovieContext';
```

and not

```
import { MovieProvider } from './MovieProvider';
```

And also import as following in `MovieList.js`

```
import { MovieContext } from './MovieContext';
```

and not

```
import { MovieContext } from './Movie';
```

Comment: Well, Problem is that it does not show MovieContext  at all, so how to import and and question was why it cant be imported

Comment: Check your `import {MovieContext}` on the `MoviesList.js` it should from `"./MovieContext"` not `from "./Movie"`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to lack understanding of what to `import`.

When you look at the code, it looks like you have a total of four `js` files.

> App.js , Movie.js , MoviesList.js , other.js(The name is unknown)

`MovieContext` and `MovieProvider` both variables are in the `other.js` file.

Therefore, the import is as follows:

```js
import { MovieProvider, MovieContext } from './other.js'; <= your file path

OR

import { MovieProvider, MovieContext } from './other'; <= your file path
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that name of my file was `MovieProvider` that's why it was showing `MovieProvider` in the options, when I saw the tutorial again found that Name of file in tutorial was MovieContext, Now after renaming from `MovieProvider` to `MovieContext`, it works as expected.
thankyou for those who replied tho. I was just tense coz   was working on a python assigment too, I complete python assignment tyesterday and today this problem is solved too.